# How to print values in table using two different length of array

Tags: java, arrays, tabular

I want to create a table with two different arrays with different dimension but after executing it does not give me proper output.

I have below code:

```
String rowHeadingkeys[] = new String[] {"heading1","heading2","heading3","heading4","heading5","heading6","heading7","heading8"};
String rowValuekeys[] = new String[] {"Text1","Text2","Text3","Text4","Text5",
                                    "Text6","Text7","Text8","Text9","Text10",
                                    "Text11","Text12","Text13","Text14","Text15",
                                    "Text16","Text17","Text18","Text19","Text20",
                                    "Text21","Text22","Text23","Text24"};

    for(int i = 0;i<rowHeadingkeys.length;i++) {

        if(rowHeadingkeys!=null) {

            patientMonitoringTable.addCell(createCell(rowHeadingkeys[i],
                    PDFUtil.BOLD_FONT,1,Element.ALIGN_LEFT));

            for(int j = 0;j<rowValuekeys.length/rowHeadingkeys.length;j++) {

                patientMonitoringTable.addCell(createCell(svo.getFields().get(rowValuekeys[j]).getValue(),
                        PDFUtil.FONT,1,Element.ALIGN_LEFT));
            }

        }
}
```

and I want to make it like below:

```
| heading1 | Text1  | Text2  | Text3  |    
| heading2 | Text4  | Text5  | Text6  |    
| heading3 | Text7  | Text8  | Text9  |    
| heading4 | Text10 | Text12 | Text13 |    
| heading5 | Text14 | Text15 | Text16 |    
| heading6 | Text17 | Text18 | Text19 |    
| heading7 | Text20 | Text21 | Text22 |    
| heading8 | Text23 | Text24 | Text24 |
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you're getting Text1 | Text2 | Text3 | for every heading.

You shouldn't be assigning j = 0 in every loop.  initialize an int index=0 outside of both for loops and the inner for loop should look like this.

```
for(int j = index; j<index + (rowValuekeys.length/rowHeadingkeys.length);j++){

}
index+=rowValuekeys.length/rowHeadingkeys.length;
```

Edit:

a better solution would be:

```
int innerIndex = 0;
for(int i = 0;i<rowHeadingkeys.length;i++) {

    if(rowHeadingkeys!=null) {

        patientMonitoringTable.addCell(createCell(rowHeadingkeys[i],
                PDFUtil.BOLD_FONT,1,Element.ALIGN_LEFT));

        for(int j = 0;j<rowValuekeys.length/rowHeadingkeys.length;j++) {
      if(innerIndex < rowValuekeys.length)
            patientMonitoringTable.addCell(createCell(svo.getFields().get(rowValuekeys[innerIndex]).getValue(),
                    PDFUtil.FONT,1,Element.ALIGN_LEFT));
           innerIndex++;
        }

    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you want 3 items from the 2nd list for each item of the 1st:

```
for(int i = 0; i < rowHeadingkeys.length;i++) {

    if(rowHeadingkeys!=null) {

        patientMonitoringTable.addCell(createCell(rowHeadingkeys[i],
                PDFUtil.BOLD_FONT,1,Element.ALIGN_LEFT));

        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {

            patientMonitoringTable.addCell(createCell(svo.getFields().get(rowValuekeys[3 * i + j]).getValue(),
                    PDFUtil.FONT,1,Element.ALIGN_LEFT));
        }
    }
}
```